# Error when building a nodejs docker image

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

This is the Dockerfile I use to generate the image

```
FROM node:12.14.1

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ADD package.json .
RUN npm install    
ADD . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

This is how i build the image

```
sudo docker build -t digi-api .
```

The output i get is:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  177.2MB
Step 1/7 : FROM node:12.14.1
 ---> 7a73e56f893c
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d5b2943c4dc3
Step 3/7 : ADD package.json .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 45ca07d61d88
Step 4/7 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 14540086976d
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@nestjs%2fcommon failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-01-20T10_17_24_065Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I am running DEEPIN os 15.11. I have a stable internet connection and i am not on any proxy.

Comment: Can you provide what exactly you did which resulted in following error?

Comment: Can you add your `Docker` file here

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Besides the other details asked above, can you also answer the questions raised by the error messages you pasted ? Did you check network connectivity ? Are you behind a proxy ? Did you check your proxy settings ? Is there any valuable information in the complete log ? Please do not reply in comments: edit your question and enrich your original post with all those details.

Comment: Anyone please help with this issue